# Android use a SMS Gateway

Tags: java, android, sms, sms-gateway

I need to put in my android applicazion a tool that uses the free service for sending free sms through internet...

I saw that many apps are able to integrate these sevices..
I tried a lot but I have not found anything useful..

So I ask you ... how can I use the gateway of `uthsms.net` (for example) for  send SMS with my Android application?

Sorry for the generic question..but I not found any starting point for resolve this question.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have same requirement can u please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Tool like Firebug to see what gets sent when you click the button on the website. I see that a POST-Request is done to uthsms.net with some parameters. You should be able to do the same POST with your app.

These are the parameter:

```
button: Send SMS
country: (some integer)
gateway: 0
hyderabad: your message
remLen: remaining length??
sindh: number to send sms to (without the +)
x: some integer
y: some integer
```

---

To send this POST-request in Android use following code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://uthsms.net");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

String data = URLEncoder.encode("button", "UTF-8") + "="
        + URLEncoder.encode("Send SMS", "UTF-8");
data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("country", "UTF-8") + "="
        + URLEncoder.encode(country, "UTF-8");
data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("gateway", "UTF-8") + "="
        + URLEncoder.encode("0", "UTF-8");
data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("hyderabad", "UTF-8") + "="
        + URLEncoder.encode(message, "UTF-8");
data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("remLen", "UTF-8") + "="
        + URLEncoder.encode(remLen, "UTF-8");
data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("sindh", "UTF-8") + "="
        + URLEncoder.encode(number, "UTF-8");
data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("x", "UTF-8") + "="
        + URLEncoder.encode("0", "UTF-8");
data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("y", "UTF-8") + "="
        + URLEncoder.encode("0", "UTF-8");
conn.setDoOutput(true);

OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(
        conn.getOutputStream());
wr.write(data);
wr.flush();


BufferedReader inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((conn.getInputStream())));

result = inStream.readLine();

inStream.close();
```

The result seems to be a html-document. Somewhere inside you should find the success message, or possible errors.

Comment: Hi D-32...How about the recaptcha_challenge_field and recaptcha_response_field....if we leave them blank will the message get sent?

Comment: When I wrote that answer there wasn't a recaptcha field. Probably they added that to prevent this kind of use.

Answer (score 0):

Try `GoogleVoice API`. It has documentation, which might help you get started.

Here's a link : https://code.google.com/p/google-voice-java/

Comment: I don't think that's what he wants, that does not allow sending "free sms though internet". It just lets you do it with voice.